# Set up java environment variable value using bat command permanently

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, command

I write a bat script to set java path in envirnment variable.
I use following command to set path -

```
setx PATH=%jdkDirDest%\bin;%PATH%.
setx PATH=%playDirDest%;%PATH%.
set PATH=%jdkDirDest%\bin;%PATH%.
set PATH=%playDirDest%;%PATH%.
```

It works fine when I am working with current session But what happen if I closed current command prompt and again open and run following command

```
java -version
javac etc.
```

It shows no java version is intall in this system

Can any one sugest me what code I use to set these environment path permanently to my matchine using bat command.

** I need bat command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **setx** without the '**=**', and **set** with it. 
Also use quotes for the values of the environment variables

```
setx PATH "%jdkDirDest%\bin;%PATH%"
setx PATH "%playDirDest%;%PATH%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a **autoexec.bat** in c:/ drive and write the following line in the file

**set path=path to java home folder;**

The path should not contain any white space.

save the autoexec.bat file and restart the PC.

Comment: I have created a file and save that to c direcotry but after restart my pc I type path command in command prompt but it is not showing path that I set in file :(